# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while setting value to excel sheet cell using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following data format in Excel 2019 sheet with name: testdata.xslx

[image]

Here in this case I am trying to read the column2 information and initiate a call to the Active Directory to get the EmailAddress and then update the Column3 (EmailAddress) with the value and save the excel sheet using Powershell script.

Here goes my powershell code :

```
function GetEmailFByLoginFromAD([string]$strfilePath, [string]$strSheetName) {
    # Validation for the input parameters
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strfilePath)) {
        throw "Please provide correct file path."
    }
    
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strSheetName)) {
        throw "Please provide correct Source sheetname."
    }
    
    
    # Open excel file and use specific sheet
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    
    $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strfilePath)
          
    $objExcel.Visible = $false
    
    if ($strSheetName -eq "") {
        $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item(1)
    }
    else {
        $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item($strSheetName)
    }      
    
    
             
    # loop for each row of the excel file
    $intRowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
    for ($intRow = 1 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++) {        
        $login = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow + 1, 2).value2
        
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($login)) {
        
            # Active Directory 

            # Logic to get the EmailAddress from Active Directory
    
            $Result = "EmailAddress from Active Directory" 
            
            if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Result)) {
                
                Write-Host "Validation of Input parameters Started..." + $Result -ForegroundColor Green

                $worksheet.cells.item($intRow + 1, 3).Value2 = $Result                

                
            }
            
        }        
    }
    $WorkBook.Save()      
    $WorkBook.close()
    $objexcel.quit()
}


GetEmailFByLoginFromAD "C:\Temp\testdata.xlsx" "Sample"
```

Can anyone help me to provide their guidance to fix this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and point out which line of code triggers the error. Sadly, the error code `0x800A03EC` is poorly documented. It seems to be a kind of catch-all exception telling that `Something went wrong. Excel might have been involved`.

Comment: Thanks @vonPryz for your reply. $worksheet.cells.item($intRow + 1, 3).Value2 = $Result is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

On further analysis, I found that the gettype() value for the $Result.Properties.mail was not of type string. I type casted the value to string and updated the code accordingly and then it started working.

Here goes the latest code:

```
function GetEmailFByLoginFromAD([string]$strfilePath, [string]$strSheetName) {
    # Validation for the input parameters
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strfilePath)) {
        throw "Please provide correct file path."
    }
    
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($strSheetName)) {
        throw "Please provide correct Source sheetname."
    }
    
    
    # Open excel file and use specific sheet
    $objExcel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
    
    $WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strfilePath)
          
    $objExcel.Visible = $false
    
    if ($strSheetName -eq "") {
        $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item(1)
    }
    else {
        $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item($strSheetName)
    }      
    
    
             
    # loop for each row of the excel file
    $intRowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
    for ($intRow = 1 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++) {        
        $login = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow + 1, 2).value2
        
        if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($login)) {
        
            # Active Directory 

            # Logic to get the EmailAddress from Active Directory
    
            $Result = Object containing the user details from Active Directory

        $emailAddress = $Result.Properties.mail 
            
            if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Result)) {
                
                Write-Host "Validation of Input parameters Started..." + $Result -ForegroundColor Green

                $worksheet.cells.item($intRow + 1, 3).Value2 = $emailAddress[0]                

                Write-Host "Updated EmailAddress Value..." $worksheet.Cells.Item($intRow + 1, 6).Value2 -ForegroundColor Green
            }
            
        }        
    }
    $WorkBook.Save()      
    $WorkBook.close()
    $objexcel.quit()
}

GetEmailFByLoginFromAD "C:\Temp\testdata.xlsx" "Sample"
```